# KDE: how to search into Konsole scrollback buffers

Tags: kde, konsole

Konsole has buffers to keep the previous 1000 lines (per tab).
I would like to have a tool to search into these buffers.
Is there a way to connect 'less' to Konsole buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the search menu.
<kbd>F3</kbd> gets you to the next search result, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to the previous.

Source: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/konsole/konsole/konsole.pdf#page=13

Comment: Thanks for the info.!